# Vectorizing (SIMD) Tree operations

Tags: c++, sse, simd, vectorization

What are some general tips/pointers on vectorizing tree operations? Memory layout wise, algorithm wise, etc.

Some domain specific stuff:

- Each parent node will have quite a few (20 - 200) child nodes.
- Each node has a low probability of having child nodes.
- Operations on the tree is mostly conditional walks.
- The performance of walking over the tree is more important than insertion/deletion/search speeds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beware, this is very hard to implement. Last year a team of Intel, Oracle and UCSC presented an amazing solution ["FAST: Fast Architecture Sensitive Tree Search
on Modern CPUs and GPUs"](http://wiki.epfl.ch/edicpublic/documents/Candidacy%20exam/kim.pdf). They won the ["Best Paper Award 2010" by ACM SIGMOD](http://blogs.intel.com/research/2010/06/faster_search.php).

Answer (score 2):

Because of the random nature of trees it's not immediately obvious how vectorizing walks would be a big plus to you.

I would lay the tree out as a flat array of (parentid, node data) "node" items, sorted by parentid, so you can at least visit the children of a node together. Of course this doesn't give you much if your tree isn't "fat" (ie low number of children on average for a node).

Your best bet though is really just to emphasize on the brute force of SIMD, because you really can't do fancy random jumps through your list with this API.

Edit: I wouldn't throw out the normal tree class you most likely have though, implement the SIMD way and see if you really gain anything, I'm not convinced you will...

Answer (score 0):

What about using spectral graph theory algorithms? They should be much easy to vectorize, as they deal with matrices.